# Como recuperar uma informação específica dentro deste array?

Tags: array, wordpress, query, objetos

Eu fiz uma consulta SQL no banco de dados do WordPress que me retornou todas as informações referentes a um pedido, porém preciso estocar em variáveis algumas destas informações e não sei como fazer.

O `$pid` retorna o **ID** dos pedidos identificados por **post_type=shop-order** na tabela `wp_posts`. Fiz um `foreach` enviando os `$pid` obtidos para a tabela `wp_postmeta` com objetivo de resgatar todas as informações de todos os pedidos.

Segue o código:

```
$sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'";

$pid = array();
foreach ($wpdb->get_results($sqlSelect) as $ids) {
    $pid[] .= $ids->ID;
}

foreach ($pid as $uid) {
    $sqlCompr = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '$uid'";
    foreach ($wpdb->get_results($sqlCompr) as $infos) {
        echo $infos->meta_key .' - '. $infos->meta_value . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Este código me retorna os seguintes valores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu consigo estocar numa variável por exempo o valor do **CEP**, tipo ...

```
$cep = meta_value['_billing_postcode'] // output -> 79037-090;
```

Comment: Dentro do foreach ja testou fazer isso? `$wpdb->get_results($sqlCompr)['_billing_postcode'] `?

Answer (score 0):

```
If ($infos->meta_key=="_billing_postcode")$cep=$infos->meta_value;
```

Isso dentro do `foreach`

;)

Comment: Podes explicar porque é que essa linha de código ajuda a resolver o problema? Assim a resposta fica completa.